# h2o deep learning package outputs one value when using autoenoder

Tags: r, deep-learning, h2o

UPDATE:
I figured out the problem, but not the solution. It is a problem with the new Java version. I started having this problem Once I updated to the latest Java.

I've been using h2o and the deep learning package for a while with no problems. Today I used it again, but I keep getting the same value for all the rows in a specific column when I extract the features from the deeplearning model. It used to work fine before. I tried using different datasets which didn't work. so I am guessing it's either my dataset (which used to work before), or something deeper than that.

This is my code. Any help is appreciated.

```
library(h2o)
localH20=h2o.init(nthreads = -1)
data=h2o.importFile(localH20, path="smsAllWords.csv", header=T)
model= h2o.deeplearning(x=1:107, training_frame = data, shuffle_training_data=TRUE, activation = "Tanh", hidden = c(100,75,50,25), epochs= 5,autoencoder = TRUE)
dl.data=h2o.deepfeatures(model,data,4)`
```

this is a sample of what the data and output looks like:
FYI: the variation of the data is higher for the rest of the matrix.

```
    data[1:10,1:10]
H2OFrame with 10 rows and 10 columns
         a1       a2       a3      a4       a5       a6       a7       a8       a9      a10
1  -0.31289 -0.10442 -0.14504 -0.1143 -0.11115 -0.12753 -0.10413 -0.28192 -0.13307 -0.27609
2  -0.31289 -0.10442 -0.14504 -0.1143 -0.11115 -0.12753 -0.10413  2.13240 -0.13307  1.80440
3  -0.31289 -0.10442 -0.14504 -0.1143 -0.11115 -0.12753  6.59090 -0.28192 -0.13307 -0.27609
4  -0.31289 -0.10442 -0.14504 -0.1143 -0.11115 -0.12753 -0.10413 -0.28192 -0.13307 -0.27609
5  -0.31289 -0.10442 -0.14504 -0.1143 -0.11115 -0.12753 -0.10413 -0.28192 -0.13307  4.40510
6  -0.31289 -0.10442 -0.14504 -0.1143 -0.11115 -0.12753 -0.10413 -0.28192 -0.13307 -0.27609
7  -0.31289 -0.10442 -0.14504 -0.1143 -0.11115 -0.12753 -0.10413 -0.28192 -0.13307 -0.27609
8  -0.31289 -0.10442 -0.14504 -0.1143 -0.11115 -0.12753 -0.10413 -0.28192 -0.13307 -0.27609
9  -0.31289 -0.10442 -0.14504 -0.1143 -0.11115 -0.12753 -0.10413 -0.28192 -0.13307 -0.27609
10 -0.31289  8.16410 -0.14504 -0.1143 -0.11115 -0.12753 -0.10413 -0.28192 -0.13307 -0.27609


dl.data[1:10,1:10]
H2OFrame with 10 rows and 10 columns
   DF.L4.C1 DF.L4.C2 DF.L4.C3 DF.L4.C4 DF.L4.C5 DF.L4.C6 DF.L4.C7 DF.L4.C8 DF.L4.C9 DF.L4.C10
1        -1       -1        1       -1        1        1        1        1       -1        -1
2        -1       -1        1       -1        1        1        1        1       -1        -1
3        -1       -1        1       -1        1        1        1        1       -1        -1
4        -1       -1        1       -1        1        1        1        1       -1        -1
5        -1       -1        1       -1        1        1        1        1       -1        -1
6        -1       -1        1       -1        1        1        1        1       -1        -1
7        -1       -1        1       -1        1        1        1        1       -1        -1
8        -1       -1        1       -1        1        1        1        1       -1        -1
9        -1       -1        1       -1        1        1        1        1       -1        -1
10       -1       -1        1       -1        1        1        1        1       -1        -1
```

edit:
I ran the same dataset and a different one multiple times, and I'll get different results. I am not changing my code at all, but sometimes it will work, sometimes it will not. Am I missing a parameter that can control this?

UPDATE:
I also tried the same data set on a different machine and it worked properly. So I am almost certain it's an issue with the other machine. I tried removing R and deleting everything associated with it then re-install it, but that didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If it worked before on the same version of H2O, then it must be a convergence issue (bad local minimum found). You can try to reduce the number of hidden layers from `hidden = c(100,75,50,25)` to `hidden=c(50)` and see if that works. Otherwise, it's almost certainly a data issue.

Comment: I did. same problem. if I run the same dataset multiple times, I will get different results. I am not changing my code at all, but sometimes it will work, sometimes it will not. Am I missing a parameter that can control this?

Comment: H2O Deep Learning is not reproducible unless you set reproducible=TRUE and seed=1234 (or any integer).  In that case, it runs in single-threaded mode, and a lot slower, but will result in the same model every time.

The fact that your model isn't giving consistent results means that the parameters aren't good. If you need a deep network, you can try a stacked autoencoder: https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/master/h2o-r/tests/testdir_algos/deeplearning/runit_deeplearning_stacked_autoencoder_large.R or look at the MSE on the training data to confirm that it actually gets better over time.

Comment: is it different than the autoencoder parameter in the deeplearning function? technically that's also stacked if you have multiple hidden layers.

I also tried the same data set on a different machine and it worked properly. So I am almost certain it's an issue with the other machine. I tried removing R and deleting everything associated with it then re-install it, but that didn't solve the problem.